# Fantasy Football Data postgre sql Get first instance

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i have a table that has draft history. call it "Draft Results".

```
team_id    pick_number    round    position    playerID
0002         01             01       WR          12
0002         01             02       QB          09
0002         01             03       TE          32
0002         01             04       RB          23
0034         02             01       WR          43
0034         02             02       WR          24
0034         02             03       QB          04
0034         02             04       QB          11
```

Only each team id has a pick for 20 rounds. I have about 7000 team_ids. I want to total which round each team took their first qb and I need help figuring out a sql query to accomplish that.

```
SELECT "Round", COUNT("Team_Id") FROM public."Draft Results"
WHERE "Position" = 'QB'
GROUP BY "Round"
ORDER BY "Round" asc
```

there are 5 different positions: 'QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE', 'D'

In this instance i would want the query to show that here was 1 team with a first qb selected in the 2nd round and 1 team where their first QB was selected in the 3rd. Currently my query would show what i mentioned AND that 1 team selected a QB in the 4th round. Even though that was not that teams FIRST QB selected (they already picked one in the 3rd)

Comment: What would the output look like?

Comment: in this case it would be team_id and round, and for the sample data i provided it would be `0002 | 02` in the first row and `0034 | 03` in the second

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simple aggregation with `min`:

```
select team_id,
    min(round) as round
from "Draft Results"
where position = 'QB'
group by team_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try MIN() aggregate function on the "Round" column

```
SELECT MIN("Round"), COUNT("Team_Id") FROM public."Draft Results"
    WHERE "Position" = 'QB'
    GROUP BY "Round"
    ORDER BY "Round" asc
```

This would then grab the minimum value for the "Round" column which would be the first or lowest 'round' that Position would be 'QB'. In your example, team_id 0034 selected a 'QB' in round 03 and round 04 but selecting the MIN() value of those two would select the first instance or lowest round they chose a 'QB' in which would be the 3rd round. I hope this helps and that I understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: How is that useful? Do you know how min and group by works?

Comment: I am still learning myself and just trying to help out as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the whole table, but constrained to the rows you want returned by virtue of the earliest round logic, I would use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM draft_results d
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT team_id, MIN(round_id) minRndQBPicked
           FROM draft_results d
           WHERE position = 'QB'
           GROUP BY team_id
           ) minRnd ON d.team_id = minRnd.team_id AND d.round_id = minRnd.round_id
```